# Character added if 2 spans have data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So I have the code shown below. The UI allows the user to select a single date, or select a date range. These are in span tags and there is a "-" I am trying to add if the toDate has a date, otherwise, do not show the "-" (dash). Tried different variations and not sure why this is not working properly. Any ideas?

Code:

```
<span class="claimedRight" style="padding-right: 1px; display:block; width: 175px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; float: right; text-align: right; padding-right: 10px;">{{ item.fromDate | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy' }} <span ng-show="item.toDate.length > 0">-</span><span>{{ item.toDate | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy' }}</span></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ng-show="item.toDate && item.toDate.toString().length > 0"
```

or just use `ng-show="item.toDate"`

Since `Date` is `Date` length will not work so convert it to `string` using `toString` and then check the length

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
  $scope.item = {toDate:new Date(),fromDate:new Date()};
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl"><span class="claimedRight" style="padding-right: 1px; display:block; width: 175px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; float: left; text-align: right; padding-right: 10px;">{{ item.fromDate | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy' }} <span ng-show="item.toDate && item.toDate.toString().length > 0">-</span><span>{{ item.toDate | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy' }}</span></span></div></div>
```

Comment: Awesome answer! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS

```
<span class="dash-prefix" ng-show="item.toDate">{{ item.toDate | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy' }}</span>
```

and

```
.dash-prefix:before {
    content: " - ";
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ko771qsj/

Comment: Great suggestion! Thanks a ton!